# Visual Studio stops at none breakpoints for no reasons

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

There is an annoying bug in VS 2008 that it will stop at some portion of the code that does not have a breakpoints. Even if I remove all the breakpoints. It will still stop at those points for unknown reasons (No exception or any problems like that). The only way for it not to stop is disabling the breakpoints. It is time consuming for me in some cases; I need to go through lots of clicks in order to go through them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a) "Even if I remove all the breakpoints. It will still stop at those points for unknown reasons"
b) "The only way for it not to stop is disabling the breakpoints."  How can you disable breakpoints that you have already removed in a)?

Comment: Have you opened the breakpoints window and removed all breakpoints from there as well? Sometimes it keeps the breakpoints even tho it doesn't indicate them

Comment: Yes. I did exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I did something silly. Instead of hitting the "continue" (F5) button, I hit the "stepping out" button instead. It might be a bug in VS 2008. I thought if I had removed all the break points, stepping out means "continue" because it should never had "stepped in" in the first place. But apparently it is not the case for VS. It will stop at some part of the code even though there are no break points set.